# Encode a string for LDAP?

Tags: python

I've got a string which I declare like:

```
s = 'jhsd*£&*sdjsdjh190-30£A'
```

I need have this as unicode to pass to ldap like so:

```
unicode_pass = unicode('\"' + str(pwd) + '\"', 'iso-8859-1')
password_value = unicode_pass.encode('utf-16-le')
add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
```

Although this does run without errors its not converting correctly which means the password isn't what it was intend to be set as.

Has anyone come across this before and solved it? Using ldap protocol v3.

TIA

Comment: where do you get `ldap` from? Is it from a python module using ldap? Also is this python2?

Comment: Yes python2 and the ldap module.

Comment: what is the indented password ?and what are you getting

Comment: Passwords in LDAP should be encoded using UTF-8 before sending to the server. The server will do byte comparison only (possibly after hashing it).